# Save SPO site as template and use script to create next sites from template

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, site-template, template

We are currently switching from SP 2016 on premise to SPO.

In SP on premise we had a site template which was used for any new project site (power shell script running at site creation). As a result the site was created with predefined contents and workflows.

Is that possible in SPO?

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

[Site templates are available in SharePoint online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/11/site-templates-are-coming-to-sharepoint-online/) modern experience as well.

You can create custom site templates using [Site designs (site templates) and site script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) capability in SharePoint online.

Follow below links for more information:

1. [Site templates are coming to SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/11/site-templates-are-coming-to-sharepoint-online/)
2. [SharePoint site template and site script overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview)
3. [Site design JSON schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema)

---

You can also use PnP provisioning engine for similar activities.

**Documentation**: [Introducing the PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)